# Zero sharp and Kunen inconsistence.

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, large-cardinals

There is some (deep/shallow/interesting/trivial) relation between:

(1) $\exists 0^\sharp$ iff $\exists j:L\longrightarrow L$ nontrivial elementary embedding.

(2) The Kunen inconsistency $\not\exists j:V\longrightarrow V$ nontrivial elementary embedding.

Comment: The embedding is not definable in $L$. And that is why $V\neq L$ if $0^\#$ exists, and in a very acute way too.

Comment: Thanks. Some reference about "is not definable"?

Comment: Well... Kunen's theorem, for one. :-)

Comment: (1) and (2) are Kunen's theorems... Is relevant this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39956/when-does-v-l-becomes-inconsistent?

Comment: I meant the second, of course.